# use (submit) button in Rails the same way as a text area or similar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, I have a Slim code block like so:

```
= form_for :paste do |f|
  = f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Title
  = f.button :priority, type: :submit, value: 0 do
    | Priority 0
  = f.button :priority, type: :submit, value: 1
    | Priority 1
```

looking at the HTML, I see that the `text_field` has `name="paste[name]"` as expected.

However, the button element does not, it's simply `name="button"`.

How can I have rails assign the correct name to the element?

Comment: I not sure but you should't have two or more elements with the same name as in your code above. See `:priority` is duplicated, what may be causing a conflict.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case, if you look at gist.github.com, they've managed to achieve the behaviour I want with their submit buttons just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [`button` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-button) sort of implies that you always get `name="button"`. But this is Rails where the only way to know for sure what it will do is to read the source. If we look at [`button`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fb24f419051aec00790a8e6fb5785eeb6f503f4a/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1797) we'll see that it is just a thin wrapper around `button_tag`:

```
def button(value = nil, options = {}, &block)
  value, options = nil, value if value.is_a?(Hash)
  value ||= submit_default_value
  @template.button_tag(value, options, &block)
end
```

And if we look at [`button_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5ba1b594aa866020fb62b961fae61a09529092a4/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L486), we'll see where this `name="button"` nonsense comes from:

```
options.reverse_merge! 'name' => 'button', 'type' => 'submit'

content_tag :button, content_or_options || 'Button', options, &block
```

I think you'll have to specify the `name` attribute manually in the HTML options if you don't want `name="button"`. Or you could just toss the helpers (since they're not exactly helping) and build the button yourself `content_tag` or even raw HTML.